# Clck Update Button twice in gridview asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

> Curently 2 click are happening for on Update button to fire.i want only single click
>   for that am also checking on !postback but still it's not working.which i have read in other Stackoverflow answer about binding the grid on 
>   updating the row which i am doing but still it's not working.
>   i am binding the grid in pageindex and rowediting event
>   need help

**backend code**

```
  protected void BindGridSubMeter()
{
    ConnectionMRI conMRI = new ConnectionMRI();
    DataSet ds = conMRI.NabersSubMetergetData(ddlBldgId.SelectedItem.Value);
    TextExclusions.Text = ds.Tables(1).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString();
    var _with1 = GridSubMeter;
    _with1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
    _with1.DataBind();

}


protected void GridSubMeter_RowEditing(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridSubMeter.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    this.BindGridSubMeter();
}

protected void GridSubmeter_PageIndexChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridSubMeter.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.BindGridSubMeter();
}


protected void GridSubMeter_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtMeterIdn = (TextBox)GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtMeterIdn");
    TextBox txCTFact = (TextBox)GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txCTFact");
    TextBox txReadStartDate = (TextBox)GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txReadStartDate");
    TextBox txReadEndDate = (TextBox)GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txReadEndDate");
    TextBox txStartKwh = (TextBox)GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txStartKwh");
    TextBox txEndKwh = (TextBox)GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txEndKwh");
    TextBox txBillPer = (TextBox)GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txBillPer");

    string MeterIdn = txtMeterIdn.Text.Trim.ToString();
    decimal CTFact = Convert.ToDecimal(txCTFact.Text);
    System.DateTime ReadStartDate = System.DateTime.Parse(txReadStartDate.Text);
    System.DateTime ReadEndDate = System.DateTime.Parse(txReadEndDate.Text);
    decimal StartKwh = Convert.ToDecimal(txStartKwh.Text);
    decimal EndKwh = Convert.ToDecimal(txEndKwh.Text);
    decimal billper = Convert.ToDecimal(txBillPer.Text);

    string leasid = GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text.Trim.ToString();
    string suitid = GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text.Trim.ToString();
    string occupant = GridSubMeter.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text.Trim.ToString();
    GridSubMeter.EditIndex = -1;
    ConnectionMRI conMRI = new ConnectionMRI();
    conMRI.NaberSubmeter(ddlBldgId.SelectedItem.Value, leasid, suitid, occupant, MeterIdn, CTFact, ReadStartDate, ReadEndDate, StartKwh, EndKwh,
    billper);
    BindGridSubMeter();

}
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridSubMeter" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="leasid" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridSubmeter_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="GridSubMeter_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridSubMeter_RowUpdating">
```

Comment: Can you edit your question in the first part? I can't understand if you want double click or not. Standard click is one click, if you want double click you must switch to javascript.

Comment: i want standard single click but currently 2 clicks are happening